# How to keep a UITableView cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code but when I select my cell it doesn't stay selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath);
    // cell.delegate = self;

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;

    let select = UIView();
    select.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = select;

    cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.row];

    // cell.selectionStyle = .blue;

    return cell;
}
```

How do I keep the cell selected? It removes the selection when I let my touch leave the cell.

Comment: `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;` comment this.& `// cell.selectionStyle = .blue;`  commented out this

Comment: Nope that isn't it

Comment: What do you have in `didSelectCell`?

Comment: Do you mean didSelectRow? I have nothing in there yet but a variable set to true

Comment: do u tried `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;` ??

Comment: It works if I press and hold but not just a tap. Why is that? Confused.

Comment: I tried with a simple demo, your code is fine, hence there is something else which interferes with the selection

Comment: probably a tap gesture i have somewhere thx

Comment: It was a tap gesture after all.

Comment: @cdub please write your solution..

Answer (score 2):

Create a int variable which store selected cell index. In didselctedIndexPath set it's value. check it's value in cellforrowatindexpath .

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var array = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
    var selectedIndex:Int? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblTitle.text = array[indexPath.row]

        if let index = selectedIndex, indexPath.row == index {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }

        let cellBackground = UIView()
        cellBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackground
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. This might help you.

```
func tableView(........) {
    if cell.selected {
        cell.selected = true
    //  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {
        cell.selected = false
    //  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is supposed to do?